# VSJitDebugger operation attempted is not supported on Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio, windbg

We have code that adds Debugger.Launch() and Debugger.Break() on certain condition, and this functionality doesn't seem to work in Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012

In previous versions of Windows this worked just fine, launching a window that would show the Visual Studio Debug dialog.

Is this a new breaking change in Windows8/Windows Server 2012?

Comment: Not reported on connect.microsoft.com, it should have been by now if this were a universal problem.  File a bug report there, you'll need to give them a better chance to repro the problem or they'll close it quickly.

Answer (score 6):

There is an open ticket with microsoft connect that contains a temporary workaround for this issue.

[Just-In-Time debugging, operation attempted is not supported](https://web.archive.org/web/20131129114408/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770786/just-in-time-debugging-operation-attempted-is-not-supported)

From comment below:

> Just change `HKCR\AppID\{E62A7A31-6025-408E-87F6-81AEB0DC9347}\AppIDFlag` from `0x28` to `0x8`.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! In short, just change HKCR\AppID\{E62A7A31-6025-408E-87F6-81AEB0DC9347}\AppIDFlag from 0x28 to 0x8.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, firstly the link doesn't work anymore and I couldn't find the corresponding item in Connect, assuming it was public. Also, I didn't have that registry flag (AppIDFlag). But even after adding it and setting the value to 8, still can't debug my service.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a change in Windows 8. I couldn't find any public documentation yet (albeit Win8 hasn't yet shipped to customers). However, I'll ask someone on the relevant team to make this information available on MSDN as appropriate.

This is part of Session 0 isolation work that started in Windows Vista.

To go back to Win7/2008R2 settings you need to do the following:

For the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows`, set the "**NoInteractiveServices**" value to *0*, which is (in Windows 8) defaulted to 1. This allows you to manually start the service that facilitates the visual dialog to you in your session, "*Interactive Services Detection*" (**ui0detect**). Without setting this key, the ui0detect service will fail to start with an error such as "Function not supported".

```
net start ui0detect
```

Of course, you can choose to make this service start automatically with Windows and always boot into being able to debug Session 0 Processes.

Comment: Tried this on RTM release, but it didn't work. Still getting the same error: "The operation attempted is not supported.".

Comment: This does not work with `Image File Execution Options` `Debugger` = `vsjitdebbuger.exe` the eventlog just says `Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: The operation attempted is not supported.`